# I've been trying to install freeradius 3. I keep getting dependency errors of not installable dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to install freeradius 3. I keep getting dependency errors. 
I get the error as:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    freeradius : Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
              Depends: libtalloc2 (>= 2.0.4~git20101213) but it is not installable
              Depends: libwbclient0 (>= 2:4.2.1+dfsg) but it is not installable
              Depends: ssl-cert but it is not installable
```

As you can notice here, all the packages shows has dependency have also been shown as not installable. What should I do?

Comment: Have you added PPAs?

Comment: I've added PPA of freeradius 3

Comment: Whatever PPA you added is incompatible with 16.04. Remove those packages and then remove the PPA. If you change WSL (or upgrade) to 18.04, freeradius 3 is in the Ubuntu repositories, compatible and tested.